# Check if WCF service exists

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, installation

What is the best way to check is the WCF service exists in a given ip and port? I want to check is the server exists on client installetion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if WCF endpoint is listening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592116/fastest-way-to-check-if-wcf-endpoint-is-listening)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to know if the "service" "exists" is to call it.

To this purpose, many services include a "Ping" operation (or perhaps a "GetServerInformation" operation) that, when called, does little or nothing, other than prove the fact that the service exists.

Answer (score 5):

I know you already marked an answer here, but you might consider checking out this related thread:
[How to check the availability of a net.tcp WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881754/how-to-check-the-availability-of-a-net-tcp-wcf-service)

There is a good alternative in there using a supported WS-Discovery method that might suit your needs, depending on your access to the service itself.

Comment: It only transfers endpoint information, not operation information. It's pretty lightweight as long as your service doesn't have lots of endpoints.