# WCF - How to detect if server is alive?

Tags: wcf

I am developing a client/server application with net tcp binding and I need to be notified if my connection to server goes down.

From server-side if a client disconnects, i can detect it instantly with CommunicationObject. Faulted event (with reliable session off). However, from Client side, it seems I have no way to know if server goes down. Same event doesn't fire. By the way I am setting receiveTimeout to infinite.  Some people suggested a heartbeat or ping function to check if server is alive. But i think at WCF level such methodologies have big impacts. After all it's not a simple packet you send , it's the whole WCF request.  What should I do ?

Comment: Related question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881754/how-to-check-the-availability-of-a-net-tcp-wcf-service>

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a common misconception that, in order to find out on the client side whether a WCF session is still alive, one has to implement some kind of custom ping or heartbeat operation on the service. However, the WCF framework, when configured correctly, already does this for you in the background.

The trick is to set the ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout to a period that is short enough. For instance, if you set it to 30 seconds, then the ICommunicationObject.Faulted event will be raised on the client proxy after 30 (minimum) to appr. 45 (maximum) seconds after a service breakdown. The exact delay depends on the rhythm of the WCF-internal session keep-alive control timer and the specific time of the breakdown.

Of course, this can only work for reliable-session capable [bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx), combined with the right session properties (ServiceContractAttribute.SessionMode, ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode, OperationContractAttribute.IsInitiating, and OperationContractAttribute.IsTerminating).